# egit pull with uncommitted changes

Tags: eclipse, git, pull

I'm working on a project in Eclipse that was cloned from a GIT remote repository. The Eclipse eGit plug-in allows you to get going without really understanding anything about GIT, which is where I was. I've eventually realized that when I do a "compare with HEAD revision" I'm not as I first thought comparing with the remote repository, but with my local repository. I understand now that I need to pull updates from the remote repository, but it's not clear what will happen to my local changes. I've not committed these changes, partly because I thought I might be updating the remote repository (I realize now that I won't) but partly because I find the Package Explorer file decoration (">") is useful in identifying the files I've modified. If I commit then I assume these indications will disappear.

My questions:

1. How do I update my local repository without losing my changes?
2. Can I do this without losing my modified file indicators?

**Update**: I thought I understood how some of this worked, but I'm really lost now, particularly by the relationship between workspace and (local) repository.

I used Team->Pull to update my repository. Since I've not committed any changes, I expected this to work without conflict, but it flagged up all the changes between the workspace and repo as conflicts (confusion #1).

I assumed I needed to use Team->Synchronize to bring changes into the workspace, as I would with other VCSs. When I do, I see the changes, but not even the non-conflict updates have been applied to the workspace and there is no "Update" operation to do this, so I don't know how to apply them (confusion #2).

For the conflicting updates, I manually merged the changes into the workspace copy and used "Mark as merged", but this seems to do nothing. The conflict is not cleared. I would expect at this point the change would just be an uncommitted change in the workspace (confusion #3).

I read elsewhere that to remove conflicts I should use Team->Add and Team->Commit, but I don't want to commit my changes as I explained originally (confusion #4).

You can see I'm confused! Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If git pull does not work, you can use this:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

not sure eclipse supports stash, so you may have to use the command line.